# wsus updated report

Tags: wsus

I have approve one update and it gave an error "faild", so after troubleshooting and get the update installed on that client.

its still appear from wsus console that computer have error.

will it be updated, or it will keep appearing as failed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seem that its only need time to be updated.